# How to allow the SQL user to CREATE LOGIN without getting a permission directly?

Tags: security, authentication, sql-server-2012, impersonation

In order to allow user to create login without getting them permission directly I desided to implement stored procedure (see test case below) with context impersonation clause `EXECUTE AS` [OWNER - in my case], but it did not work for `CREATE LOGIN` statement - I getting an error **"User does not have permission to perform this action."**.

I suspect that database level (user scope) impersonation does not make sense on the server level (login scope).

Maybe there is other way to implement this? Or maybe I'm wrong and procedure should work?

Any advice will be appreciated

```
select system_user;
-- I'm dbo
go

create procedure dbo.CreatePlayer
    @player_name nvarchar(10),
    @player_password nvarchar(20)
with execute as 'dbo' /* or execute as owner - whatever */
as begin    
    exec('CREATE LOGIN ' + @player_name + ' WITH PASSWORD = '''+@player_password+''', CHECK_POLICY = OFF');
    --CREATE LOGIN Player1 WITH PASSWORD = 'Password', CHECK_POLICY = OFF
end;

create login Unknown with password = 'Unknown', check_policy = off;
create user Unknown for login Unknown;
grant execute on [dbo].CreatePlayer to Unknown;

execute as user = 'Unknown'
    select system_user
    -- I'm Unknown

    -- throws "User does not have permission to perform this action."
    exec dbo.CreatePlayer 'Player1', 'Password';
revert;

select system_user;
-- I'm dbo

-- if I specify [with execute as 'dbo'] above in the procedure declaration
-- , this line throws "User does not have permission to perform this action."
-- too - that was surprising for me, because I'm dbo
exec dbo.CreatePlayer 'Player1', 'Password';

-- cleanup
drop login Player1
drop user Unknown
drop login Unknown
drop procedure dbo.CreatePlayer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [**<kbd>here</kbd>**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverfaq/archive/2009/07/24/how-to-impersonate-the-privileges-to-create-a-login-using-the-stored-procedures-using-execute-as-clause.aspx).

Because users do not have a server level privileges (create logins permission for example), we must execute our SP under login level impersonation (insted of user level). To do this we need:

1. Remove `with execute as 'dbo'` clause from SP header
2. Add `execute as login='login_with_security_admin_privileges'` clause to SP body

In my case it looks like this:

```
create procedure dbo.CreatePlayer
    @player_name nvarchar(10),
    @player_password nvarchar(20)
as begin   
    exec('CREATE LOGIN ' + @player_name + ' WITH PASSWORD = '''+@player_password+''', CHECK_POLICY = OFF') 
    as login = 'login_with_security_admin_privileges';
end;
go
```

And also it is necessary to grant impersonate permission:

```
use master;
go
grant impersonate ON login::[login_with_security_admin_privileges] TO Unknown
go
```